# Programmatically changing the views inside NSSplitViewController

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssplitviewcontroller

From the NSSplitViewController class reference at
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSSplitViewController_Class/index.html
I understand that it has a property that is an array of objects oftype NSSplitViewItem. It also has methods to insert and remove NSSplitViewItem objects.
However, there is no documentation for NSSplitViewItem. How do I create such an object?

I saw one example online:

```
let svi = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: vc) where vc is of type NSViewController
```

But found no Apple documentation at all. It almost seems like Apple wants developers not to programmatically add/remove NSSplitViewItem

Could someone tell me how to create a NSSplitViewItem?

Comment: With NSSplitViewController you don't have to play with items, you can use addChildViewController: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40708392/3275080

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow no public documentation is available for `NSSplitViewItem`.  But there is a little trick for scenarios like that. Type `NSSplitViewItem` in Xcode and then ⌘-click it. You will be able to see the 'header file' for `NSSplitViewItem`.

There are multiple initializers available.

Example:

```
let item = NSSplitViewItem(viewController: self.viewController)
splitViewController.addSplitViewItem(item)
```